# I got a notice every time I upload an image

Tags: 7, media

Suddenly, I got this error every time I want to upload an image. It does not matter if it is an file field, or an IMCE import to CKeditor. I got the message, and the image does not upload. Do you have any idea?

> Notice:getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Read error! in image_gd_get_info() (line 349 of /www/mysite.com/modules/system/image.gd.inc

My "tmp" and "sites/files" directories have the permission 777, php5-gd is already installed.
I have also problems uploading attachments files, after upload them the size of the file is 0 bytes.

[In this conversation](http://drupal.org/node/81613), they suggest two solutions: one is changing the path of the "tmp" directory, but it doesn't work for me; the other is related to favicon set.
I remember that I uploaded a favicon in theme settings as I always do, and I think after that I began to have the issue. I am not really sure if it is related because this bug happened in older versions of Drupal.

Some images of my problems.

[image: Image notice]

[image: 0Bytes in attachments to node]

Comment: You should update your question with more info, not comment on it :) You should provide more info about the files setup you have. Public/Private/Tmp file-dirs and permissions on those.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is already fix. The hosting provider had changed some permissions of my shared account.

Comment: What was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue in Drupal before and the issue was with the installed GD library on the server. Our server admin fixed it with instructions that he found here - http://drupal.org/node/134331

Comment: my phpinfo said that is already installed, GD Support enabled GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible), but I will talk to the server admin to give a check

Comment: As you say it was a server configuration problem, the sever admin had  changed some permissions